# Specifying a complex random-effects structure in metafor

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis, meta-regression, metafor

I am working on a project in which I am using `metafor` to carry out a single-paper meta-analysis. My project contains data from 5 different studies; each study contains pairs of tasks that participants had to perform:

- Studies 1–4 contain two tasks each, so each study contributes one pair of tasks.
- Study 5 contains four tasks, so it contributes a total of 6 unique pairs of tasks.

For each task pair within each study, the outcome is 10 *c*-statistics. In short, 10 different models with decreasing information content are fit to each task pair. As a result, these 10 *c*-statistics are expected to decrease from 10 (most information) to 1 (least information). Let's call these outcomes $y$.

Thus, my response variable is $y_{ijk}$ for study $i$, task pair $j$, and *c*-statistic $k \in \{1,\dots,10\}$. Studies 1–4 contribute 10 *c*-statistics each and Study 5 contributes 60 *c*-statistics, which are logit-transformed for analysis. I also have a $100\times100$ error variance-covariance matrix $V$ that's calculated on the logit scale.

***I am principally interested in the effect of $k$ on $y$ within each study. Secondly, I am interested in how heterogeneity changes as a function of $k$ at each level.***

Although Studies 1–4 seem straightforward to model, Study 5 seems a bit more difficult. For one, I want to be sure it does not dominate my meta-analytic result—the data were all collected in a relatively small sample and they are all from the same subjects. Second, it seems as if I should account for its asymmetry in the random-effects structure. Suppose Study 5's tasks are A, B, C, and D. We are left with the following task pairs:

1. A vs. B
2. A vs. C
3. A vs. D
4. B vs. C
5. B vs. D
6. C vs. D

**A vs. B** should be more correlated with **A vs. C** than it is **C vs. D**, since **A vs. B** and **A vs. C** both contain A. However, it is not clear what exactly this correlation structure should look like as I do not have a natural distance measure between pairs of tasks.

My current model is rather naïve:

```
  rma.mv(c.logit ~ k,
       data = df,
       V = V,
       slab = study,
       random = list(~ k | study, ~ k | contrast),
       struct = c("GEN","GEN"))
```

where `k` is 1–10 and `contrast` is a task pair, which is currently modeled to be different for each contrast and each study (i.e., `paste0(study,".",contrast_name)`). However, it is worth noting that the task pair from Study 2 is the same as the first task pair from Study 5.

Is there a preferred way to specify my random-effects structure so that:

1. Study 5 does not dominate my analysis
2. I can account for the asymmetry in Study 5
3. I can account for the task pair similarity in Study 2 and Study 5, task pair 1. ***Edit***: I believe this (#3) can easily be accomplished by recoding `contrast` so that it is specific to each contrast *name* rather than each contrast within each study. I.e., "A vs. B" is contained in Study 2 and Study 5, so I can simply specify contrast as a factor named "A vs. B" rather than "Study 2.A vs. B" and "Study 5.A vs. B". Is this correct and be equivalent to nesting with partially crossed RE?

Thank you in advance, and of course, I am happy to provide additional information as needed.